# Best Practice to Rollback an update command when an exception happens

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, sql-update, rollback

I have a case where i update a record in Sql Database, then make a call to Rest Api. the question is if my call to Rest Service fails i would like to Rollback/revert the record that i updated.

I am using Entity frame work and Asp.net Web api,

Is there any best practice/way, i can handle this situation.

Comment: Use transactions

Comment: but both my update and calling to Rest client are in different classes.
can i still use transactions

Comment: Yes, the update and rest call are both made by the same block of code somewhere and that is where your transaction would be.

Comment: thanks, used transactionScope and it solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a transaction, see documentation:

[Entity Framework Working with Transactions (EF6 Onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Sounds more like a comment than an answer.